# Can a notification trigger a bot in a chatroom?

Tags: bots, slack, chatops

I am new to ChatOps and started with Slack. I got a doubt.
A bot can be triggered by some conversation happening in the chat room. But I wanted to know does vice versa happens? I mean can a bot be triggered from outside and then bot performs some operations in the chat room?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes slack bots can be triggered from outside.

For simple example, you can trigger a post from the bot to a channel by contacting the slack API endpoint. You can see all documentation here [api.slack.com](http://api.slack.com)

Comment: Thanks Arianto :)

Comment: We use the slack API to have bots report messages into chatrooms based on external events. The key is to always make sure it's always obvious that it's a `bot` sending the message and to name them appropriately. We have several bots, one of them is named `[BOT] release.sh`